# react how to onClick whole of the group without a button inside

Tags: reactjs

This is a group in my react.

```
<div onClick="this.redirect">
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>
        item 3
        <div>subItem 1</div>
        <div>subItem 2</div>
        <button onClick={this.btnClick}>click me</button>   
    </div>  
</div>
```

I want that if I click whole of the div group, It will redirect.

However, I have a button inside the group, which I want to do something else without redirect.

How can I do?

Comment: Your question title is not appropriate for your its content.

Comment: @SaeidAlidadi Can you suggest how to change my title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event.stopPropagation()` inside the `btnClick` function if you don't want a redirection on button click, like this:

```
btnClick(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); //will prevent the click from propagating to parent
    //stuff here
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div onClick={// redirection logic here}>
          <div>item 1</div>
          <div>item 2</div>
          <div>
            item 3
            <div>subItem 1</div>
            <div>subItem 2</div>
            <button onClick={this.btnClick}>click me</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is stopPropagation's purpose is stop parent's event bubble?

Comment: @jimmy Yes, exactly!